# Embed a page within WordPress dashboard?

Tags: comments, facebook, dashboard, moderation, embed

We're using Facebook Comments for the comment functionality on our WordPress blog. I thought it'd be nice to embed the page with [Facebook Moderation tools](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments?view=queue) on the WP Dashboard. That way, we can immediately see who commented on what when we log in.

I've looked for the functionality to embed an html page in a dashboard widget but I haven't managed to find something. Does anybody know if this is possible?

Comment: Pretty sure you can just add an iframe to a dashboard widget, or are you talking about the Facebook api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function facebook_setup_function() {
    add_meta_box( 'facebook_widget', 'Facebook Moderation Tools', 'facebook_widget_function', 'dashboard', 'normal', 'low' );
}
function facebook_widget_function() {
    include ('facebook.php');
}

add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'facebook_setup_function' );
```

add the above to your functions file and replace the include url with the php file you wish to include into your dashboard.

## Setting it up ;

Use the facebook.php and add an iframe to it, or ajax call to load the facebook tools, then simply just echo that file into your dashboard page :)

Comment: Thanks you! This works great to embed html pages in the dashboard. Only problem is that it seems that Facebook won't allow to access their moderation tools via an iframe. :S Nothing to be done about that for now. Lets hope they'll allow it in the future.

Comment: that is bizzare, but i guess they need account authorization and so on, so maybe facebook doesn't like the cross domain integration (good to know) thanks matey and i'm glad it worked for you

Comment: thanks Xavier! Been looking all over to add a widget properly to my dashboard. Your function has been an excellent start for me to make my own widget, cheers!

Comment: @Piet Your most welcome Piet i am glad to of been some assistance to you :)